# How to create an arc without borderlines using shaperenderer of libgdx

Tags: libgdx, draw, borderless

I'm a newbie at `libgdx` and trying to achieve a border less arc like first image with `shaperenderer`. 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/41CUu.png

But It draws this
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Ftg.png

My small line of code is ;

```
shapeRenderer.arc(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,300,0,170);
```

How can manage to create an arc without borders. I will need to change angle range of the arc. So I cannot use a static image or sth like that.

Thanks

Comment: I finally found it!

Thanks to this answer;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699321/libgdx-drawing-arc-curve