# how to draw part of image in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I have this

[image]

and I need to draw only this part

[image]

I didn't find drawArc in SpriteBatch, how can it be done in libgdx?

update

I already have some textures drawing by SpriteBatch.

Reading [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/1186#) it's not a good idea to use SpriteBatch and ShapeRenderer.

Comment: Here's a RadialSprite class that can be drawn with SpriteBatch: https://github.com/xoppa/world/blob/master/src/com/xoppa/android/misc/RadialSprite.java

Comment: thank you very much, it's work fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to draw an arc you can use [ShapeRenderer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) instead of Batch and its **arc** function

```
    arc(float x, float y, float radius, float start, float degrees)
```

simple example how to use it (in **render** method):

```
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

    shapeRenderer.arc(yourX, yourY, yourRadius, yourStart, yourDegrees);

    shapeRenderer.end();
```

if you want to draw arc without "arms" you can look here: [libgdx drawing arc curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699321/libgdx-drawing-arc-curve)

---

If you want to render fragment of Texture two solutions comes to my mind:

- render filled arc with color of background using shapeRenderer over the image and covering it making the illusion of partial arc rendering. Remember that Shaperenderer call will flush() your batch but if you won't overdose it it shouldn't affect the performance at all
- clearing the **Pixmap** pixels that are not included in the arcus shape you want to render. You can take the Pixmap using

  ```
  Pixmap pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();
  ```

  then you will just iterate over it and copt to the new pixmap only these pixels that are inside your arc shape and create new **Texture** based on the new Pixmap then render the new texture

  ```
  Pixmap newPixmap = new Pixmap(pixmap.getWidth(), pixmap.getHeight(), pixmap.getFormat());

  for(int i = 0 ; i < pixmap.getWidth(); i++)
      for(int j = 0 ; j < pixmap.getWidth(); j++)
          if( isInArc(i, j) ) newPixmap.draw(i, j, pixmap.getPixel(i, j) );

  Texture newTexture = new Texture(newPixmap);
  ```

  of course the **isInArc()** funct you need to write yourself due to how you will define an arc and so on - you can look at [Intersector](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html) to make it easier

Comment: so why not to just get a texture region from texture? do you want something like arcus fragment of circle texture?

Comment: i want to draw something like loading speedometer bar, so there is a bottom image and a top image, the top image is only shown by % state. I did this using canvas with BitmapShader and canvas.drawArc() without any engines, but I don't know how to realize it in libgdx

Comment: why can't you just render filled arc with color of background over the image you want to render just partially and then just chaning arc degree?