# Drawing a circle and arc in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I need to create a pie chart in libgdx for a finance app. Could you please point me an example or code snippet to have an idea on it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libgdx drawing arc curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699321/libgdx-drawing-arc-curve)

Answer (score 0):

you can use shaperenderer:
read this [classMethods](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) shaperendere has :

- arc(float x, float y, float radius, float start, float degrees)
- circle(float x, float y, float radius)
- curve(float x1, float y1, float cx1, float cy1, float cx2, float cy2,
  float x2, float y2, int segments)
- ....

OR

```
public class Arc extends ShapeRenderer{

    private final ImmediateModeRenderer renderer;
    private final Color color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);

    public Arc(){
        renderer = super.getRenderer();
    }

    public void arc (float x, float y, float radius, float start, float degrees) {
    int segments = (int)(6 * (float)Math.cbrt(radius) * (degrees / 360.0f));

    if (segments <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("segments must be > 0.");
    float colorBits = color.toFloatBits();
    float theta = (2 * MathUtils.PI * (degrees / 360.0f)) / segments;
    float cos = MathUtils.cos(theta);
    float sin = MathUtils.sin(theta);
    float cx = radius * MathUtils.cos(start * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
    float cy = radius * MathUtils.sin(start * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);

    for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
        renderer.color(colorBits);
        renderer.vertex(x + cx, y + cy, 0);
        float temp = cx;
        cx = cos * cx - sin * cy;
        cy = sin * temp + cos * cy;
        renderer.color(colorBits);
        renderer.vertex(x + cx, y + cy, 0);
    }
  }
//// or 
public void arc (float x, float y, float radius, float start, float degrees, int segments) {
    if (segments <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("segments must be > 0.");
    float colorBits = color.toFloatBits();
    float theta = (2 * MathUtils.PI * (degrees / 360.0f)) / segments;
    float cos = MathUtils.cos(theta);
    float sin = MathUtils.sin(theta);
    float cx = radius * MathUtils.cos(start * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
    float cy = radius * MathUtils.sin(start * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);

    if (shapeType == ShapeType.Line) {
        check(ShapeType.Line, ShapeType.Filled, segments * 2 + 2);

        renderer.color(colorBits);
        renderer.vertex(x, y, 0);           <--- CENTER
        renderer.color(colorBits);
        renderer.vertex(x + cx, y + cy, 0); <--- LINE TO START POINT
        for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
            renderer.color(colorBits);
            renderer.vertex(x + cx, y + cy, 0);
            float temp = cx;
            cx = cos * cx - sin * cy;
            cy = sin * temp + cos * cy;
            renderer.color(colorBits);
            renderer.vertex(x + cx, y + cy, 0);
        }
        renderer.color(colorBits);
        renderer.vertex(x + cx, y + cy, 0); <-- LINE TO END POINT
...
}
```

Comment: When I tried your code , It work good but While drawing the continues arc for Pie chart there is a gap if I use segments. why ?

Comment: @iappmaker   did not understand what you mean. please explain more

Comment: When a arc is drawn the curved path is not smooth.. it is scrambled.. any way to smooth